# OpenGL texture crooked

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to upload a texture in OpenGL but the texture is crooked.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const char * vertShader = GLSL(430,

    in vec2 position;
    in vec2 texcoord;

    out vec2 coordinates;

    void main() {
        coordinates = texcoord;
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

);

const char * fragShader = GLSL(430,

    in vec2 coordinates;

    out vec4 color;

    uniform sampler2D texture;

    void main() {
        color = texture(texture, coordinates);
    }

);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (not glfwInit())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    GLFWwindow *window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(720, 480, "Textures", 0, 0);

    if (not window)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = true;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        +1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

    GLuint elements[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertShader, 0);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragShader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");

    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);

    glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void *)(2 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);

    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    int width, height;

    unsigned char * image = SOIL_load_image("happyface.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

    SOIL_free_image_data(image);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    do {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    } while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS
                        && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);

    glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? As you can see the texture is crooked and repeating, but the texture is just one smiley face.

That is the result:

[image: result]

And that is the texture:

[image: texture]

Comment: Does setting `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to `1` help?

Comment: It doesn't, unfortunately.

Comment: @yayuj you must have put it in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm no OpenGL guru, but some graphics systems require textures that are multiples of 2 or 4 pixels wide.

Your texture is 479 wide - add another column of pixels and I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Maybe you meant power of two textures? Cause 480 is divisible by 2 but clearly is a `NPOT` texture.

Comment: @Nazar554 indeed, it's not a power of two, but the displayed image is clearly consistent with there being a one pixel per row offset being applied, and I'm 99% confident that a 480-wide image will not show this.

Comment: It's weirdly working now. Thank you. - I read about that once and I thought that it was fixed.

Comment: @MrAlmighty it might even be a limitation of the `SOIL_load_image` function rather than OpenGL itself.

Comment: I think it's OpenGL itself, I was reading about that and it seems that the powers of two makes the texture optimized for the graphics hardware. - Even though modern hardware allows others without being power of two, it's not working. (mystery).

Comment: Why no body talk about these stuff? Why are these not documented anywhere. Had the same issue with same solution for Android MediaRecorder. No documents there either. Thank you so much!